# How to change opacity of background image?

Tags: android

Is there any way that I could change the opacity of the background image that I set on the XML file? Also, I wanted to justify the text that I'm going to put in the xml file, however, as I researched for this same issue. Android studio doesnt support justify text yet. However, I tried to change to webview instead of textview however I'am having a lot of errors calling it to my main activity java since I used case statement to call the layouts and the java file of the webview is not fragment but rather activity. Your response would be much appreciated. Thank you

Here is the XML file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/minnions1"
android:id="@+id/minnions1"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Safe and Responsible usage of Computer,Internet and Email"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/title1"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity ="center"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Using facilities and equipments should always be safe and useful in Information and Communication Technology (ICT)
like computer, email, and internet. It is important for us to study the guides and safe usage of computer, internet
and email in schools.\n \n"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/content1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also, Here is the java file

```
package com.android.pet.view;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.doepiccoding.navigationdrawer.R;

public class Lesson1 extends Fragment{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.onepointone, null);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can not quite understand your second part of the questing..where is your webview,it is now visible in the code uploaded..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try This

```
View backgroundimage = findViewById(R.id.background);
Drawable background = backgroundimage.getBackground();
background.setAlpha(80);
```

here backgroundimage is for your understanding you can replace your layout which background you want to set opacity

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.onepointone, null);

        View backgroundimage = findViewById(R.id.minnions1);
        Drawable background = backgroundimage.getBackground();
        background.setAlpha(80);

        return rootView;
    }
}  


However there is a red line under findViewById saying Cannot resolve method findViewById(int)

Comment: @Dreamer try using rootView.findViewById(R.id.minnions1);

Answer (score 4):

You can change it programatically using setAlpha(50) method and in xml you can use android:alpha="0.5" 
1 is max so 0.5 means half transparent .

You can also change your design a little bit.
Instead of doing this , do this

```
<FrameLayout>
<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/background" 
    android:alpha="0.3" />
<LinearLayout>
//Same as before
</LinearLayout>
```

Make framelayout your parent and put your linear layout as a child and rest will remain the same . Give your imageview width of height of match parent and that's it.

Comment: However it will affect my textview if I will implement that inside my xml file. I already tried it and the whole layout got affected. What I want to do is just the background image to be affected not the textviews

Comment: Well in that case you have to change your design a little bit, use framelayout and use imageview inside it and just change the alpha of that image and it will not effect the others

Answer (score 0):

If You need To Change the opacity of your image that is to be used as background i have a solution for this but you need to change it pragmatically

```
   Drawable mDrawableImage= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mybackgroundimage);

         //   opacity in (alpha) set
   mDrawableImage.setAlpha(50);// 50 %

        // setting the images as background to your Layout eg.Constraint,Relative or else
    mLinearLayout.setBackground(mDrawableImage);
```